Magnetic tubes or magnetic field lines around a black hole?
A picture is worth thousand words:

Magnetic field lines, unlike magnetic tubes, have a continuous distribution. Recent pictures of black hole magnetic structure show tubes. Is there a model that explains them?

Is the yellow/orange color actually a black hole? Or is it the accretion disk around one?

A recent question on that image and what it means: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808084/123208

Unfortunately you need quite a lot of words to explain what you are looking at - and it is not a picture of magnetic field lines.
